# junit5 and mockito testing approach

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, mockito, junit5, assertion

I'm new to writing unit tests. I've started writing unit tests for my java classes using Mockito and Junit5. I'm not really sure if what I'm following is the right way to test a class.

Testing approach followed :-

- Spy the class under test and check if it is returning the correct response. Example :-

Java Class A :-

- Let's assume that this class has a method that performs deserialization using Jackson or Gson library.

Code :-

```
public Student deserializeResponseBody(String responseBody) {
        return GsonUtil.fromJson(responseBody, Student.class);
    }
```

Test Java Class A :-

- Spy Class A in this test class. Call the method of Class A and check
  if I'm getting the correct response using Assertions library.

Code :-

```
@Spy
private A a;

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource(value = "readResponseFromFile")
Student student = a.deserializeResponseBody(responseBody);
assertNotNull(student, "Deserialized Response is null");
```

Please let me know if there's a better approach that I can use for writing the tests.

Comment: Please show your code instead of describing it in prose. It will greatly simplify understanding what are you are trying to do.

Comment: @johanneslink Please let me know if you need any other details

Comment: Make your sample code compilable and minimal. From the code you currently show I have to make a lot of assumptions and can’t just copy it to try out. The less a reader has to do themselves for reproducing your problem the more likely she/he will provide a useful answer.